# Which Teamcity plugin is being used?

Tags: teamcity

We have several Teamcity (2018.2.4) plugins installed. Some of them are quite ancient and I would like to uninstall/disable them but they have similar names to some other plugins and I don't want to break any build.

How do I verify if particular plugin is being used by any build and what build is it ?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible, I recommend you copy your TC, start the new instance, start to delete the plugin one by one and run all configuration. 
If nothing happens - delete this plugin.

btw, don't delete bounded plugins.